# Relational database JOIN return excessive values

Tags: mysql, join

Using relational database usually i am joing the table using INNER JOIN. When querying out the data from the joined table it returns excessive amount of value. As an illustration i have created a dummy data table as below.

[image]

The table sequence are Operation can have many daily and daily can have many activity and each activity is unique by its activity UID.

Usually  i will INNER JOIN for example to join Operation table with Activity table to query out each breakdown of class, phase, ops, root per operation. However it returns excessive amount of Durationhrs. The worst case if joined all the 3 tables (Operation, Daily, Activity) it will return massive hours value beyond believe.

My questions are

1. Where did i went wrong?
2. What kind of join to make it right?
3. If this cannot be done what is the best method to join?

My database like this

```
CREATE TABLE Operation
    (`Operationuid` varchar(3), `operationname` varchar(10), `owner` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO operation
    (`Operationuid`, `operationname`, `owner`)
VALUES
    ('AA1', 'Cow', 'Jon Letoy'),
    ('AA2', 'Chicken', 'Ridikill' ),
    ('AA3', 'Snake', 'Mighty'),
    ('AA4', 'Sheep', 'The great'),
    ('AA5', 'Pig', 'Peon');


CREATE TABLE Activity
    (`Operationuid` varchar(3), `DailyUID` varchar(10), `ActivityUID` varchar(55), `Class` varchar(3), `Phase` varchar(3), `Ops` varchar(3), `Root` varchar(3), Duration int);

INSERT INTO Activity
    (`Operationuid`, `DailyUID`, `ActivityUID`, `Class`, `Phase`, `Ops`, `Root`, `Duration`)
VALUES
    ('AA1', 'DD1', 'AC1', 'AB1', 'PH1', 'OP1', null, 12),
    ('AA1', 'DD1', 'AC2', 'AB1', 'PH2', 'OP1', null, 2),
    ('AA1', 'DD1', 'AC3', 'AB2', 'PH2', 'OP2', 'RR1', 3),
    ('AA1', 'DD1', 'AC4', 'AB3', 'PH3', 'OP3', null, 5),
    ('AA1', 'DD1', 'AC5', 'AB4', 'PH4', 'OP4', 'RR2', 1);

CREATE TABLE Daily
    (`Operationuid` varchar(3), `DailyUID` varchar(10), `Dayno` varchar(55), `Daycost` decimal);

INSERT INTO Daily
    (`Operationuid`, `DailyUID`, `Dayno`, `Daycost`)
VALUES
    ('AA1', 'DD1', 1, 1000),
    ('AA1', 'DD2', 2, 2000),
    ('AA1', 'DD3', 3, 3000),
    ('AA1', 'DD4', 4, 4000),
    ('AA1', 'DD5', 5, 5000);
```

---

```
Select operation.*, daily.*, activity.* from Operation
INNER JOIN daily on daily.operationUID=operatin.operationUID
INNER JOIN activity on activity.operationUID=operation.operationUID
```

This will return 25 result instead of only 5 that i need why?

Comment: What is your query? You could use [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) to setup up your tables & query.

Comment: First i joined the table using inner join based on operationUID between operation table + activity table and then query out duration hours for class,phase,ops,root...give sometime to construct the query

Comment: Please read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and "[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask )".

Comment: What we need to see is the actual query - not an explanation in words. Why not, as I suggested, create your tables & add your data & actual SQL query in SQLFiddle - that way we have a chance of giving you some help.

Comment: Please see the example codes it returns 25 result instead of 5 that i need

Comment: You've joined activity to itself.  
Should it be joining to Daily on OperationUID AND ActivityUIOD or something like that?

Comment: Sorry about that i've corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a little problem on your JOIN. You joined the `Activity` table with itself here: `INNER JOIN activity on activity.operationUID=activity.operationUID`

You may want to correct that as:

```
Select operation.*, daily.*, activity.* from Operation
INNER JOIN daily on daily.operationUID=operation.operationUID
INNER JOIN activity on operation.operationUID=activity.operationUID
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a4ae9/8

On that result you will see 25 rows as result. That's because when you query many tables without JOIN operations what happens is a cartesian plane between the involved tables which will result in the multiplication of numbers of rows in all tables, on your case it WOULD be 5*5*5. But since we have the `JOIN` operation you receive the equivalence between `operation` and `daily` tables therefore 5 registries than you add another join with `activity` table which has 5 more registries to the `Operationuid` equals to `AA1` so it will result in a each registry of the first join (operation with daily) with all registries on the activity table.

Comment: Yup sorry i have corrected it and do you know why am i getting 25 results instead of 5 only that i need

Comment: You see the the worst case is that in my real database in the activity itself is differentiated with its own unique UID. when i join between operation, daily, activity it gets ten thousands of values. Can you advise what is the best join and how should i use it 

* Operation - operationUID
* Daily - operationUID, dailyUID
* Activitiy - operationUID, DailyUID, activityUID

Do you see the relation between one another where the operation is the biggest parent and when join all using inner join it tend to get ten thousands of value hours

Comment: Well that's, i'm sure, because of the data you have on those tables, maybe you forgot to mention some other relation that exists between then. A good thing would be you, from that sample you gave show what exactly are the result you need. That way we will understand way better to give you a proper answer.